typeorm how to combine `queryBuilder` with an external database
I have a FileEntity like this:

@Entity()
export class FileEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  @CreateDateColumn()
  createdAt: Date;

  @UpdateDateColumn()
  updatedAt: Date;

  @DeleteDateColumn()
  deletedAt: Date;

  @Column({ default: null })
  originalname: string;

  @Column({ default: null })
  mimetype: string;

  @Column({ default: null })
  url: string;

  @ManyToOne(() => UserEntity, (user) => user.files)
  user: UserEntity;

  @Column({ default: null })
  size: number;


  videoMetadata: any;
  }
}


videoMetadata (like video length, resolutions etc) is stored in an external database (video provider). Is it possible to somehow map this data from external provider to my videoMetadata property? This is how I'm using findAll method for fetching files and I'd like to somehow use lefyJoin to join external table:

  findAll(data: InputFilePaginationDto) {
    const service = this;

    function getFilesQuery(skip?: 'mimetype') {
      const query = service._fileRepository.createQueryBuilder('file');
      query.leftJoinAndSelect('file.user', 'user');
      if (data.userId) {
        query.andWhere('user.id = :userId', { userId: data.userId });
      }

      if (data.minSize) {
        query.andWhere('file.size >= :minSize', { minSize: data.minSize });
      }

      if (data.maxSize) {
        query.andWhere('file.size <= :maxSize', { maxSize: data.maxSize });
      }

      if (data.mimetypes && skip !== 'mimetype') {
        query.andWhere('file.mimetype IN (:...mimetypes)', { mimetypes: data.mimetypes });
      }

      return query;
    }

    const query = getFilesQuery();

    return pagination(
      data,
      query,
      ['file.originalname'],
      {
        default: 'file.updatedAt',
        createdAt: 'file.createdAt',
        updatedAt: 'file.updatedAt',
        originalname: 'file.originalname',
      },
    );
  }


